# Google Measurement Protocol & Self-Referrals

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I'm using the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol to manually log page views of RSS feeds (can't use the usual Analytics JavaScript here).

Everything works fine, but Google Analytics warns me that I got a lot of "self-referrals". The warning details are:

> A significant portion of referral traffic to property < MY_DOMAIN > is from the following hostnames, which may be self-referrals:
>
> < MY_DOMAIN >
>
> Self-referrals are referrals from pages within your own domains. Self-referrals can obscure the actual sources of traffic to which conversions and other engagement on your site should be attributed. As a result, your referral metrics could be inaccurate. Further, self-referrals could be indicative of improperly-configured cross-domain tagging. Your users could be generating a session per domain, which would artificially inflate session counts.
>
> There are multiple different Analytics misconfigurations that can cause self-referrals. Users navigating from an untagged page on your site to a tagged page can appear as self-referrals. Users navigating from one subdomain on your site to another subdomain that uses a different cookie domain can appear as self-referrals. If you track multiple domains in one web property, users navigating across multiple domains on your site without linker parameters set up to transfer cookie information properly can appear as self-referrals.
>
> To avoid self-referrals, ensure all pages on your site are correctly tagged with the Analytics tracking code, make sure that cross-domain tracking is configured correctly on all your pages, and check your cookie domain settings in your tracking code to be sure that all subdomains in a domain are using the same cookie domain.

And sure enough, I got about 99% (pretty much all the hits on the RSS feeds) of all my referrals from my own domain - which is definitely not the case, because those hits usually come directly from RSS readers.

In my C# code, where I do the HTTP POST the Google Analytics, I use `Request.UrlReferrer` to get the referrer of the current request and post it to Analytics:

```
// context is an instance of HttpContext

var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.google-analytics.com")
};

[...]

string referrer = null;
if (context.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    referrer = context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
}

var postContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("v", "1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("tid", Config.GoogleAnalyticsTrackingId),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("cid", clientId),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("t", "pageview"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dh", context.Request.Url?.Host),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dp", context.Request.Url?.PathAndQuery),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ua", context.Request.UserAgent),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("uip", context.Request.UserHostAddress),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dr", referrer)
});

client.PostAsync("collect", postContent).Wait();
```

I can't see a reason why I get so many referrals to my own domain. I know that `Request.UrlReferrer` can be null, but that should not be a problem here, should it? What can I do to solve this "too many self-referrals" problem? I could just check the referrer for my own domain, and then don't send this referrer to Analytics, but that does not seem very smart to me ;)